# num_rows always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ap_promo WHERE wp_ap_promo.promocode = '".$promocode."' AND wp_ap_promo.business_id = " . $id .";");
echo $wpdb->num_rows;
```

My `num_rows` always gives a 1, even though there are no results.

EDIT: seems like the problem was in my SQL-tables. But accepted answer also seems to work.

Comment: **WARNING**: Don't forget to [properly escape](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) your queries. What you have here probably contains a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.count.php) the values instead.

Like this:

```
global $wpdb;

$test = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ap_promo WHERE wp_ap_promo.promocode = '".$promocode."' AND wp_ap_promo.business_id = " . $id .";");
echo count($test);
```

if it still does not work, use something like this:

```
if($test != null) {
   echo count($test);
} else {
   echo 0;
}
```

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: You mean `count()` in my SQL query?

Comment: It seems like there was an error in my SQL, with some records I have missed. But I also tested yours, and it works as well. But my original code also works again now. When no records are found, it actually returns 0.

Comment: good :D then accept so the topic can be closed! :D I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Ok, but I think you should remove your first line, as it doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: Depends on how the query is structured. Note that in some cases, that can be right ;) but, just because your original way worked, I removed it :)